# How to add a css file in laravel?

Tags: php, html, css, laravel, laravel-8

I want to apply `margin-bottom` on `#createNewBook`, I added a CSS file in laravel by using `<link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/css/style.css">`. But it's not working. Can anyone tell me how to add a CSS file to my laravel project?

This is my HTML code in laravel:
[image]

This is CSS code:
[image]

This is my directory format:

[image]

And this is the output:

[image]

Comment: only things in the `public` folder are accessible publicly (served by the webserver) ... nothing below that folder is directly accessible ... so you have to put assets in the `public` folder some where ... the `public` folder is the root of your site

Comment: okay, let me check.

Comment: @lagbox it's not working

Comment: Please take a look at the official Laravel Mix documentation on how to compile assets. There you will find all the information you need. https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/mix#main-content

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to put your assets folder into the public folder because only the things in the public folder are accessible publicly.

[image]

And then in the blade.php file use the following syntax to load CSS.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{asset('assets/css/style.css')}}">
```

Comment: but after 'npm run build' I got 'public/build/assets/app.222e333.css' how I can include this one? laravel 9.X

Answer (score 6):

Put the assets folder in public then in the blade file use this syntax to load css

```
{{asset('assets/css/style.css')}}
```

Comment: @MubeenAhmad Consider marking the answer as the correct one to help others having the same trouble.